# What is the different between spring 2.5.6 and spring 2.5.6.SEC01

Tags: spring

The download page on http://www.springsource.com/download/community mentions:

- spring-framework-2.5.6.SEC01
- spring-framework-2.5.6

What is the difference between those two versions? Why the SEC01 numbering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at this:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=70899

Here is the announcement link, for a security fix:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=70912